# Read file local storage windowsphone

Tags: windows-phone, local-storage

I try to read xml files from my windows application.
In this one, I add a folder in Assets/Mocks/clubic.xml (build action : content) to use the data in the xml file as a mock.
So I try to use the following code

```
         var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
            var installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
            try
            {
                StorageFile sampleFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets/Mocks/clubic.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            try
            {
                StorageFile sampleFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/Mocks/clubic.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

I obtain for the two cases, the same exception 
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FileReadWrite.MainPage.d__17.MoveNext()}

I try to use this code

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            if (local != null)
            {
                // Get the DataFolder folder.
                var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("Assets/Mocks");

                // Get the file.
                var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("clubic.xml");

                // Read the data.
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    this.textBlock1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
```

I still obtain the same issue.
Can you help me.

best regards,
Alexandre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

StorageFile sampleFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync(**@"Assets\Mocks\clubic.xml"**);

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've done in an app of mine to read a file that's built as Content:

```
var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Assets\Mocks\clubic.xml", UriKind.Relative));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream)) {
    this.textBlock1.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```